# buffer-face-set resets font size

Tags: emacs, fonts

I am using Emacs 24.5.1. 
Starting with `emacs -Q`, if I have (at least) two active windows and I increase the font size using

```
(text-scale-increase)
```

Then execute these two commands (to change the background color and then back):

```
(buffer-face-set '(:background "#110000"))
(buffer-face-set 'default)
```

Then the font size resets to the default. The strange thing is that if I now call `(text-scale-increase)`, the font size is increased as if the current font size is not actually the default.

Is this normal? How can I fix this so that changing the background color does not resets the font size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal.

`text-scale-increase` uses a minor mode `text-scale-mode` which tracks the font scaling with a variable `text-scale-mode-amount`.  When you run `(buffer-face-set 'default)` you are resetting your font size, but not the scale value that is saved by `(text-scale-increase)`.  When you use a `text-scale-*` function again (and it sets the face font size) it adjusts scale based on the value of `text-scale-mode-amount`.

You might want to look at using the `zoom-frm` package.  It defines some great convenience functions.

Comment: Is there a way to reset the background color to default without resetting the font size?

Comment: You can get the background of the default face and set it to that `(buffer-face-set (list ':background (plist-get (custom-face-attributes-get 'default nil) ':background)))`